# CMapStringToOb::Lookup Won't Work with Japanese Characters

Tags: c++, unicode, mfc

Does anyone know why `CMapStringToOb::Lookup` doesn't work in Japanese?  The code loads a string from the string table, and puts it into a CMapStringToOb object. Later it loads the same string from the string table (so it is guaranteed to be exactly the same) and calls `CMapStringToOb::Lookup` to find it.  It works in all languages that we've translated to and tested, except for Japanese which can't find the string in the CMapStringToOb object.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your app Unicode or MBCS? Not that I would have an explanation in one of those cases. Just trying to narrow down the scope.